# How to design AC/DC PSU PCB for safety

Tags: ac, mains, protection

I want to convert 220V AC to a 12V DC output. I will then feed this 12V DC into a buck regulator to step it down to 5V DC.

Thus far I have done the 12V DC to 5V DC.

[image]

However, I am not sure what sort of protection I should include on the VAC_IN(L) and VAC_IN(N). The datasheet ([here](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Powerline_AC-DC/RAC10E-K_277.pdf)) does not include a design PCB specs.

Can someone assist me on how should the inputs be designed VAC_IN(L) and VAC_IN(N) (what protection do I need, how to go about designing it,...)

Edit 2:

PCB layout:

PS1 is the AC/DC PSU

[image]

[image]

Edit 3:
[image]

Comment: Is your application an OVP III type or worse: [Read this if you don't know](https://meanwellpowersupplies.com/power-supplies-for-overvoltage-category-ovc-iii-applications/)

Comment: What is your application? Does it require a power supply that has a higher-than-OVC_III power supply?

Comment: @Andyaka my application is OVC II. I am feeding mains voltage from a wall socket.

Comment: Then maybe your question now boils down to "how should I safely route mains AC tracks on a PCB and, what form of connector do I need to connect to the mains AC"? I'm trying to help you figure out what you do know and what you don't know.

Comment: @Andyaka I have added Edit 2 in my post. The connector I wanted to use was a phoenix 2.54mm screw terminal. I have also added the routing

Comment: OK that's good but you need to check that the phoenix connector pad spacing is sufficient for your maximum AC voltage; personally speaking I don't think it is if you want to use the full range of the recom power supply. So, you say 220 volts AC but what could be the maximum supply (ignoring surges). It might be 10% higher or 20% higher <-- you have to figure this out based on what country you are in and how reliable the supplies are.

Comment: @Andyaka how do I get this spacing using the voltage?

Comment: Is this really what you need? Can a wall plug power supply with a 12 V output do?  Can a OEM power supply internally work? This can avoid a lot of hard questions, reading regulations and standards, reliability issues and sleepless nights.

Comment: @DDuck A wall plug 12V DC will not work, I want to use mains has the input power. Is the AC/DC in my post not the OEM PSU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Recom power supply is good for connecting to an internal wall socket. In fact, it's better than that and can be hard-wired to a distribution panel in a home. This is because it has an OVP III categorization. So, it then boils down to the copper-to-copper spacing requirements on your PCB.

Although some say that [IPC-2221](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/%7Eshuman/NEXT/CURRENT_DESIGN/TP/MATERIALS/IPC-2221A(L).pdf) is a little over-the-top on clearance distances vs voltage supply, it's an industry standard with this table appearing on page 42: -

[image]

This governs the type of phoenix connector you use. For instance, I have chosen a **peak** AC operating voltage of 301 volts to 500 volts (blue box on the left).

I have also selected column B2 because the solder pads for the phoenix connector will be uncoated. Hence, the clearance needed between the pads needs to be 2.5 mm.

For tracks under a solder resist you can use column B4 (0.8 mm).

Having said all of that, I would spray some lacquer on the solder side pads of the phoenix connector and apply as much clearance as you can for mains AC tracks under a solder resist.

**Note about IPC-2221: I used version A and I think the current one is revision BPV2-0 so, be advised that you should double check that this table is still current.**

Comment: Thanks Andy, the pitch for this connector is 2.540mm. Which is above the recommended separation distance. See EDIT 3 in my post.

Comment: @JoeyB no, not the pitch. I'm talking about the gap between the pads on the circuit board needs to be greater than 2.5 mm.

Comment: Sorry the pitch is 5.08mm, but the gap (please confirm in edit 3 pic) between the pads is 2.540mm

Comment: @JoeyB theoretically correct but, why not elongate your pads horizontally and make them thinner in the critical vertical direction and get a gap of significantly better than 2.54 mm. Play safe.